# How can I use this variable C#

Tags: c#

```
string delimiter = "id=ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDirecciones style="HEIGHT: 19px; WIDTH: 190px" type=text readOnly value=" ;
```

i can't use this delimiter because between style and type i have semicolons, but I need to use this as a delimiter

I need the semicolons, because the program search a word after this delimiter

Comment: _"How can I use this variable"_ _what_ variable? _"I can't use this delimiter"_ _what_ delimiter?

Comment: escape the double quotes with a backslash.

Comment: Escape the doublequotes: \" or ""

Comment: It looks like you're trying to manipulate some HTML. Although the learning curve will be steeper, it's almost certainly better to start with something like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) that's *designed* to help you manipulate HTML, rather than your current approach that seems to be based on mangling strings together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the double quote, since that is problem cutting the string

```
string delimiter = "id=ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDirecciones style=\"HEIGHT: 19px; WIDTH: 190px\" type=text readOnly value=" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Single Quotes Inside Double Quotes

```
string delimiter = "id=ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDirecciones style='HEIGHT: 19px; WIDTH: 190px' type='text' readOnly value=''" ;
```

Comment: What if it contains double quotes, not single quotes?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar is double quotes is valid in HTML i mean browser will understood HTML ???

Comment: Of course double quotes are valid HTML! My understanding even is that single quotes are the exception...

Answer (score 0):

Quote quotation marks properly. You can easily do this using the following string literal:

```
string delimiter = @"id=ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDirecciones style=""HEIGHT: 19px; WIDTH: 190px"" type=text readOnly value=" ;
```